# Getting unbounded direction in C++ API

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm trying to implement Benders decomposition as a solution approach to my problem in C++ API. Meanwhile, I use "getRay" function to get extreme directions of the dual sub-problem to build a feasibility cut in the relaxed master problem. The way in which I'm using "getRay" function is like this.

```
IloNumVarArray var(env);
IloNumArray val(env);
cplex.getRay(val, var);
```

I'm ending up with extreme directions in the var/val arrays. My principle concern relates to the way of using "getRay" function. As far as I know, "getRay" fills this IloNumVarArray with the variables that are non-zero in the extreme direction and the corresponding values of these variables will be in the IloNumArray. The order of the elements in the array returned by getRay() is unspecified. Furthermore, it returns only the non-zero values of the unbounded. I don't know how to map each extreme direction to the corresponding expression in the feasibility cut. More specifically, I've know idea how to build my feasibility cut by the values in the val and var arrays! I was wondering if anyone would please do me a favor.
Regards

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in your post to tell you what's going in. Use your debugger to track it down, or post a short, self-contained piece of code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Actually, I've difficulty in using "getRay" function. Could you please let me know which part is not clear?

Comment: A few more lines explaining your formulation would help. What are you trying to optimize? What do the variables and subscripts represent? And if possible, share the exact error text that you are getting. Then someone here might be able to help.

Comment: I do not understand if your problem is implementing it or if you have trouble with the math to formulate the cut?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your exact problem is, to get a ray you should turn off the presolve first and use primal simplex as your solution method and use getRay. You can refer to this post "http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2010/07/finding-extreme-rays-in-cplex.html". 
I hope it is helpful to you.

Niraj

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is explained (with code snippets) in [this post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014397575#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014643899).

Answer (score 0):

`getRay` function has 2 inputs `(val, var)`. It fills the `val` with the non-zero coefficients and `var` with the corresponding variables.

For example if val returned with (1.5, 2.5) and var returned with (x1, x3); you can say that 1.5x1 + 2.5x3 is an extreme direction.

For mapping the values you can check `x[i].getId() == var[j].getId()`.

Edit: You can set properties to variables with `setStringProperty` and `setIntProperty`. You can access the properties for mapping the values.